# Extract list elements at diagonal above with numpy.tril

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I want to extract a nested list's elements at diagonal above with [numpy.tril](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html). From my understanding, set parameter k>0, it will return diagonal above. However, my code doesn't return the result expected.

```
np.tril([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], 1)
>>> array([[1, 2, 0],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

expected output:

```
array([1,2,3],
[4,5,0],
[7,0,0,])
```

Comment: You are confusing the diagonal and the anti diagonal. And you are confusing lower and upper too...

Answer (score 1):

You can flip the array, get the *upper* triangle, then flip it back:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

In [3]: np.triu(a[:, ::-1])[:, ::-1]
Out[3]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 0],
       [7, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues. First, **[`np.tril`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html)** (as indicated in its name) gives a *lower* diagonal. Second, triangular arrays are conventionally the mirror image of your desired output.

We can take a peek at the [source code](http://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.0/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py#L414-L439) for **[`np.triu`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html)** and adapt it for a new `triu_anti` function via [`np.fliplr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html#numpy.fliplr):

```
def triu_anti(m, k=0):
    m = np.asanyarray(m)
    mask = np.fliplr(np.tri(*m.shape[-2:], k=k-1, dtype=bool))
    return np.where(mask, np.zeros(1, m.dtype), m)

res = triu_anti([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

print(res)
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [4, 5, 0],
#        [7, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `T` for twice

```
np.tril(a.T,0).T
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [0, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 9]])
```